# How to reduce NodeTree Viewport Lag on Many Nodes, (Animation Nodes)

Tags: animation-nodes

I have a kinda big project, fully based on "Animation Nodes" addon. The problem is, that FPS drops to **10-20** when just scrolling or manipulating with nodes in Node Tree Viewport. It also affects FPS when viewing animation in 3D-Viewport, so I've to hide the working area (CTRL+SPACE). It is the same problem as in the default blender's node editor, but much worse. Instead of blender handling over 1k-1.5k nodes to drop down to that low FPS, Animation Nodes stuck at about 300-400 in one node tree. *(when i switch to node tree with not that many nodes, everything works fine, despite the fact that I've over 1k nodes in total)*

###### What can be done, to optimize Node Tree Viewport to handle more nodes without dropping FPS THAT much?

---

> Addon ver. - 2.2.2
>
> Blender ver. - 2.79, 3.0

---

Current PC setup: *(in case, if the problem may be in weak hardware)*

- *Intel core I5 7400*
- *GTX 1050*
- *24GB RAM*

[image: Animation Nodes project statistics]
[image: Blender handling 2236 nodes (278 Nodes and 1958 Reroutes), or ~875-~1250 nodes only in Shader Editor, and getting about the same FPS when scrolling]

Comment: Have you disabled automatic execution of the node trees in the right hand side panel ?

Comment: As Gorgious mentioned, the automatic execution isn't necessary. If you wanna see the change, just move one frame forward or backward, then it recalculates if have checked the "recalculate on frame change" checkbox

Comment: [here is a video sample of the problem](https://youtu.be/DhYcReF3ePQ), and no, the problem is not in auto-exec., even if it is completely disabled